# How store bigdecimal value in orc format?

Tags: java, orc

Orc format [defines](https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html) `double` and `float`. Is there a way to store `BigDecimal` value with scala and precision attributes?

Comment: BigDecimal is a compound type (a class)

Comment: The ORC **Decimal** type would be suitable as for its precision attribute, a feature that Float and Double do not possess. Maybe https://github.com/eclecticlogic/eclectic-orc . I did not find any direct BigDecimal support

Answer (score 0):

From API specification:

> `public final class MathContext`

Immutable objects which encapsulate the context settings which describe certain rules for numerical operators, such as those implemented by the **BigDecimal** class.
The base-independent settings are:

precision: the number of digits to be used for an operation; results are rounded to this precision
roundingMode: a RoundingMode object which specifies the algorithm to be used for rounding.